# How do multiple users write to same directory in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can multiple users write files to same directory in HDFS without having any disturbance to write operations?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple users cannot write a file that resides on a HDFS path at the same time. However since you've mentioned **files** (NOT a file) in the question, it is possible for clients/users to write different files in the same HDFS Path without any issues. Because, when you are writing different files on a same HDFS path, the blocks/data on the blocks of these files are independent from each other and NameNode would not restrict users to perform the write. However, if it's a single/same file that the clients are trying to write - NameNode would not permit this operation and the request has to wait till the write lock is revoked on a particular data node.

More about HDFS WRITE operations below,

[Link 1](https://data-flair.training/blogs/hadoop-hdfs-data-read-and-write-operations/)

[Link 2](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Replication+Pipelining)

[Link 3](https://data-flair.training/blogs/hdfs-data-write-operation/)

Hope this helps!